# Install Java for just one user under Redhat Linux?

Tags: linux, redhat, java, user-accounts

Is it possible to install a JDK on Linux (specifically RH 7.x) so that it exists in only a specific user's space?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Download the JDK unpack, add "bin/" to your $PATH and change/add $CLASSPATH, $JAVAHOME if
needed.

Ex:

```
$ cd
$ mkdir -p java/src/
$ mv jdk-6u12-linux-i586.bin java/src/
$ cd java/src/
$ chmod ug+x jdk-6-linux.bin 
$ ./jdk-6-linux.bin
$ cp -R jdk1.6.0_12/* ../
$ cd
$ echo "PATH=\$HOME/java/bin/:\$PATH" >> .bash_profile
$ source .bash_profile
```

And your'e done..

Comment: In other words, not the RPM but the tar-ball.

Answer (score 0):

What's stopping you just using discretionary access control (i.e. users and groups) to achieve this?

Comment: For one user, the solution proposed by rkthkr is the easiest

Comment: The extreme rust on all of my Unix/Linux knowledge.  Prior to last week, I haven't launched PuTTY since June of 2007. :-)

Comment: No idea why this was downvoted. It's a legitimate answer, particularly if later more users are supposed to get access.